# ng-invalid focus on input or select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have validation form in angularjs with input and select elements.
When form is submitted focus should jump to first element (input or select) which has class ng-invalid.
I have code to focus on input element, how to add rule with select element...
Focus on first element witch class ng-invalid. Without specifying input or select it will not work because very first element with this class is .

```
$('form').submit(function() {
            var invalid = $.find("input.ng-invalid:first");
            $(invalid).focus();
        });
```

html:

```
<form id="form" method="post" name="form" role="form" novalidate class="form-horizontal"  ng-submit="submitForm()">
<fieldset class="attributes col-md-12" ng-disabled="readOnly" ng-cloak>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="select" class="col-sm-wrap-4 control-label">Select:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6" ng-switch="readOnly">
            <select id="select" name="select" ng-model="form.select" ng-required="true">
            </select>
            <div class="validation-error" ng-show="form.submitted">
                <span ng-show="form.select.$error.required">This field is required</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input" class="col-sm-wrap-4 control-label">Input:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6" ng-switch="readOnly">
            <div ng-switch-default="false">
                <input type="text" id="input" name="input" ng-model="input.value"
                class="form-control" ng-required="true"/>

                <div class="validation-error" ng-show="form.submitted">
                    <span ng-show="form.input.$error.required">This field is required</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="saveButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-header" ng-click="update(form)">Save</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `$.find("input.ng-invalid:first");` this seems invalid/syntax error.

Comment: @Jai you can't say exactly. But OP is saying not working, so might be invalid.

Comment: $.find("input.ng-invalid:first"); -- this works for me

Comment: what about situation when select is invalid?

Answer (score 3):

Try this selector:

`$("input.ng-invalid, select.ng-invalid, textarea.ng-invalid").eq(0).focus();`